# How delete image of cloudinary to Android side?

Tags: android, delete-file, cloudinary

I want to delete image upload to Cloudinary to Android side, on the documentation https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_java/tree/master/cloudinary-android I can't see that.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the cloudinary image from android client application with the below code:

```
Cloudinary cloudinary=new Cloudinary(CLOUDINARY_URL)
Map deleteParams = ObjectUtils.asMap("invalidate", true );
cloudinary.uploader().destroy("public_id",deleteParams );
```

> Make sure you have a valid image public_id.

Comment: Doesn't work for Android you need `api_secret`,  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply api_secret

Answer (score 1):

Deleting images requires using a signed authenticated API, the signature is based on your account's `api_secret` which must be excluded from your client-side code, and therefore should be done on your server-side. So you can make a request from the Android app, which requests the server perform the deletion request.